# In node.js, how can I create a UDP socket that automatically binds to an available port?

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp, datagram

As stated in the title, is it possible to create an UDP socket that automatically binds to an available port, instead of having to hard code the port number?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I know this works for TCP, I gusse it should work as well for UDP:

https://github.com/indexzero/node-portfinder

Comment: That package is TCP only.